# My GraphQL mutation is not saving to my MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, graphql, netlify

As the title says, my mutation `addEatery` isn't saving to my database. In my resolvers, the query works great but the mutation for some reason doesn't. I'm still quite new to GraphQL mind you.

```js
const Eatery = require("./server/models/Eatery");

module.exports = db => ({
  Query: {
    eateries: async () =>
      await db
        .collection("eateries")
        .find()
        .toArray()
  },

  Mutation: {
      addEatery: async (_, {id, name, description, address, city, postCode, phoneNumber, businessHours, foodType, veganFriendly, vegetarianFriendly, halal, kosher, dogFriendly, childFriendly, ethical, alcohol, price, website }) => {
        const eatery = new Eatery({id, name, description, address, city, postCode, phoneNumber, businessHours, foodType, veganFriendly, vegetarianFriendly, halal, kosher, dogFriendly, childFriendly, ethical, alcohol, price, website});
        eatery.save();
        return eatery;
    },
  } 
});
```

Now it returns the object of new data that I mutate with in the GQL playground but when I check the DB it hasn't updated there.

For some reason this code isn't happy when I use `await`. It just gives me a `500` response back from the server :(

```js
  Mutation: {
      addEatery: async (_, {id, name, description, address, city, postCode, phoneNumber, businessHours, foodType, veganFriendly, vegetarianFriendly, halal, kosher, dogFriendly, childFriendly, ethical, alcohol, price, website }) => {
        const eatery = new Eatery({id, name, description, address, city, postCode, phoneNumber, businessHours, foodType, veganFriendly, vegetarianFriendly, halal, kosher, dogFriendly, childFriendly, ethical, alcohol, price, website});
        await eatery.save();
        return eatery;
    },
  }
```

I'm using Netlify Lambda functions to host this.

My index file for my endpoint below:-

```js
const { ApolloServer } = require("apollo-server-lambda");
const typeDefs = require("./typedefs");
const resolvers = require("./resolvers");
const connectToMongoDB = require("./db");

exports.handler = async function(event, context) {
  const db = await connectToMongoDB();
  const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers: resolvers(db)
  });
  return new Promise((yay, nay) => {
    const cb = (err, args) => (err ? nay(err) : yay(args));
    server.createHandler()(event, context, cb);
  });
};
```

My DB file

```js
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const URI = process.env.DB_URI;
const DB_NAME = process.env.DB_NAME;

let cachedDb = null;
module.exports = () => {
  if (cachedDb && cachedDb.serverConfig.isConnected()) {
    return Promise.resolve(cachedDb);
  }
  return MongoClient.connect(URI, { useNewUrlParser: true }).then(client => {
    cachedDb = client.db(DB_NAME);
    return cachedDb;
  });
};
```

This is the typeDefs

```js
const { gql } = require("apollo-server-lambda");

module.exports = gql`
  type Eatery {
    id: String!
    name: String!
    description: String
    businessHours: String
    address: String!
    city: String!
    postCode: String!
    phoneNumber: String
    foodType: String!
    veganFriendly: Boolean
    vegetarianFriendly: Boolean
    halal: Boolean
    kosher: Boolean
    dogFriendly: Boolean
    childFriendly: Boolean
    ethical: Boolean
    website: String
    alcohol: Boolean
    price: String
  }
  type Query {
    eatery(id: String!): Eatery
    eateries: [Eatery]
    getFoodType(foodType: String): [Eatery]
  }
  type Mutation {
    addEatery(id: String, name: String!, description: String!, businessHours: String, address: String!, city: String!, postCode: String!, phoneNumber: String, foodType: String!, veganFriendly: Boolean, vegetarianFriendly: Boolean, halal: Boolean, kosher: Boolean, dogFriendly: Boolean, childFriendly: Boolean, ethical: Boolean, alcohol: Boolean, price: String, website: String): Eatery
    editEatery(id: String, name: String, description: String, businessHours: String, address: String, city: String!, postCode: String!, phoneNumber: String, foodType: String, veganFriendly: Boolean, vegetarianFriendly: Boolean, halal: Boolean, kosher: Boolean, dogFriendly: Boolean, childFriendly: Boolean, ethical: Boolean, alcohol: Boolean, price: String, website: String): Eatery
    deleteEatery(id: String, name: String, description: String, businessHours: String, address: String, city: String!, postCode: String!, phoneNumber: String, foodType: String, veganFriendly: Boolean, vegetarianFriendly: Boolean, halal: Boolean, kosher: Boolean, dogFriendly: Boolean, childFriendly: Boolean, ethical: Boolean, alcohol: Boolean, price: String, website: String): Eatery
  }
`;
```

Any idea as to why this mutation isn't actually saving this data to my MongoDB would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes, you should `await` the save. "*It just gives me a 500 response back from the server :(*" - then somewhere in your server logs there should be the cause of the exception.

Comment: Good idea, unfortunately mlab doesn't have any server logs to my dismay :(